# Python Django Config Question

Tags: django, ubuntu

I am getting this error, how would I go about fixing this?

```
daniel@daniel-toshiba~ $ python
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41)
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

Comment: Did you do "setup.py install"?

Comment: Where would I do this, what is the standard dir for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like django isn't installed to the site-packages directory, or is not in your Python path.

Comment: I followed this chapter in the django book: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/

Comment: There's really no need to follow any complex instructions. Just untar Django and add it to your $PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

See Option 1 here for much more straightforward instructions than the page you were following: http://www.djangoproject.com/download/